# Не работает детальный просмотр "НОВОСТИ"

Tags: php, битрикс, компоненты, битрикс24

Только-только стал осваивать 1С Управление сайтом.
В руки попался сайт с такой проблемой: Сайт на двух языках, RU и UA, вся информация дублируется в ручную, естественно, как и новости. Они выводятся на главную.
Если в RU версии кликнуть на детальный просмотр новости, перекидывает на главную, но ссылка в строке поиска принадлежит самой новости, так же каталог и новости отображаются c UA версии.

В UA версии данной проблемы не наблюдается.

Инфоблоки прописаны одинаково за исключением элементов расположения папки. Детальнее ниже. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Файл urlrewrite.php:

```
<?php
$arUrlRewrite=array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/online/([\\.\\-0-9a-zA-Z]+)(/?)([^/]*)#',
    'RULE' => 'alias=$1',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/desktop_app/router.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/video([\\.\\-0-9a-zA-Z]+)(/?)([^/]*)#',
    'RULE' => 'alias=$1&videoconf',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/desktop_app/router.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^\\/?\\/mobileapp/jn\\/(.*)\\/.*#',
    'RULE' => 'componentName=$1',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/mobileapp/jn.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  51 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/acrit.googlemerchant/(.*)#',
    'RULE' => 'path=$1',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/acrit.googlemerchant/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/bitrix/services/ymarket/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/ymarket/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/online/(/?)([^/]*)#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/desktop_app/router.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/stssync/calendar/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:stssync.server',
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/stssync/calendar/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  50 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/ua/catalog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/ua/catalog/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  68 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/catalog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/catalog/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  75 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/ua/news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/ua/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  72 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^\\??(.*)#',
    'RULE' => '&$1',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog.section',
    'PATH' => '/ua/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/rest/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/rest/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  76 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
);
```

Прикладываю скрины настроек RU и UA:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки ЧПУ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл index.php RU:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news", 
    "news", 
    array(
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "news",
        "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "7",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "Info",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "8",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "catalog",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/news/",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
        "USE_FILTER" => "N",
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
        "USE_RATING" => "N",
        "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
        "USE_RSS" => "N",
        "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
        "USE_SHARE" => "N",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "news" => "",
            "section" => "",
            "detail" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        )
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Файл index.php UA:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news", 
    "news", 
    array(
        "LANG" => "ua",
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "N",
        "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "8",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "Info",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "8",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "catalog",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/ua/news/",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
        "USE_FILTER" => "N",
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
        "USE_RATING" => "N",
        "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
        "USE_RSS" => "N",
        "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
        "USE_SHARE" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "news",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "news" => "",
            "section" => "",
            "detail" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        )
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Как видите настройки идентичны, согласно своей папке, но UA версия работает без нареканий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос с помощью специального файла .access.php, прописал права доступа и все работает. (в папке /news/ вместе с файлом данного инфоблока index.php)

```
<?
$PERM[".access.php"]["2"]="R";
$PERM[".access.php"]["3"]="R";
$PERM[".access.php"]["4"]="R";
$PERM[".access.php"]["6"]="R";
$PERM[".access.php"]["8"]="R";
$PERM[".access.php"]["7"]="R";
$PERM[".access.php"]["5"]="R";
$PERM[".access.php"]["*"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["2"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["3"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["4"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["6"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["8"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["7"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["5"]="R";
$PERM["index.php"]["*"]="R";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в файле index.php RU:

```
    "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
        "news" => "",
        "section" => "",
        "detail" => "/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
    )
```

Должно быть:

```
    "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
        "news" => "",
        "section" => "",
        "detail" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
    )
```

Comment: Поправил, но никак не повлияло. Все равно спасибо!